# How to show hidden text in Radzen if i'm using rz-text-truncate when i'm pointing on the сut text(...)?

Tags: c#, sass, blazor, truncate, radzen

I want to see it like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bqRU.png)

I'm currently working with Radzen, a tool for building web applications, and I've run into a bit of a snag. I'm using the rz-text-truncate component to handle long text by truncating it and showing ellipsis (...) at the end. However, I'm looking to add an extra layer of interactivity.

Here's the deal: I want to allow users to see the hidden or truncated text when they hover over the ellipsis. Essentially, I'm trying to create a way for the full text to pop up or become visible temporarily when the user hovers over the truncated portion.

I've been thinking about using HTML, CSS, or maybe even a touch of JavaScript to achieve this effect. Has anyone else dealt with a similar situation in Radzen or in web development in general? How did you go about it? Any tips, code snippets, or advice would be incredibly helpful.

My main concern is making sure the user experience remains smooth and intuitive while solving this issue. I want to strike a balance between revealing the hidden content and maintaining the overall design and functionality of the application.

I appreciate any insights you might have or any solutions you can suggest. Thanks in advance for your help!"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.